# Display all y label in a large Heatmap using boost - Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

I have a large dataset to plot using a heatmap in Highcharts. It has around 18000 lines. I am using boost library. Here is the fiddle (it is a little bit slow): https://jsfiddle.net/joaosalles/vyegb16L/18/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  
  data: {
    csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML
  },
  
  chart: {
    type: 'heatmap',
  },
  
  colorAxis: {
    stops: [[0, '#ffffff'],
            [0.5, '#fffbbc'],
            [0.9, '#c4463a'],
            [1, '#c4463a']
           ]
  },           
        
  series: [{
    keys: ['x', 'y', 'value', 'code'],
    boostThreshold: 1,
    turboThreshold: 20000
  }]

});
```

I need to reach some goals:

1. Display each and every y in yAxis. This is going to impact the chart height. I have already tried using chart.setSize and didn't work. I don't know if I have to use some label setting or other kind of configuration.
2. Show the colors in heatmap. I think this is related to the size of the chart. But it is not working properly right now.

I am not sure if I am struggling with some browser limitation or other issue.

I'll appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this a result which you want to achieve?

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qy9fpak1/

1. You can set the `chart.height` to some huge amount - https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.height or try to show all ticks - https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickAmount
2. You need to set the `colorAxis` config, like min and max or define the `stops` array - API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colorAxis.stops

Comment: It is almost this, in your fiddle the yAxis have a 20 unit step. I am struggling to show each and every label in yAxis. Do you have any idea to implement this?

Comment: I realize that your fiddle works well using heights untill 32767. When I use a larger number, the console returns "NS_ERROR_FAILURE: "

Comment: You need to know what is your data y range. I estimated that it is around 3000. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ey45udzf/ `I realize that your fiddle works well using heights untill 32767. When I use a larger number, the console returns "NS_ERROR_FAILURE: "` I connot see this error on my device. Test on the newest version of the Google Chrome browser.

Comment: I have updated my Chrome and it does not show that message anymore. The yAxis is now complete, but the heatmap is not matching with the axis. In my browser, the heatmap occupies the upper half of the chart. Tooltips are working properly, but it is possible to check that the strong colors are not correponding with the higher values presented in tooltip. Something is mismatched. I've been struggling with this for several days, and I can't find where the problem is.

Comment: @JoaoSalles it's related to the `colorAxis` and your huge data range. A lot of points have a value around 0 which is white. You need to define particular stops color for your data. https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vw4mpauq/ API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colorAxis.minColor https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colorAxis.stops

Comment: I tried to config minColor and stops without sucess. Using your fiddle, in my browser, the heatmap does not fill the entire chart, as you can see [here](https://imgur.com/a/rDcJUpm). There is a point that should be red and it is not. Everything below the blue line seems to be not rendered.

Comment: Do you have the same behaviour in your browser?

Comment: I've just discovered that when I use boostThreshold: 20000 the heatmap renders perfectly, in other words, the heatmap starts from bottom and shows perfect correspondence between colors and values for each y label. But I think that, with this action I am disabling the boost mode. It can be an boost mode issue?

Comment: Interesting case, it might be the boost kind of the limitation. Could you reproduce your case and report it on the Highcharts Github issue channel? https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues

Comment: Sure. I'll do it now. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in current Highcharts version (8.2). If someone wants to follow here is the link to the issue:

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/14368